# Little Schemer - IDE

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

I am reading through the book "The Little Schemer" and looking for an IDE that allows me to play with the code in the book. I have looked at DrRacket and REPL, but not sure if these are the best IDEs for this learning goal. Also - is there any source / website that has the code of the book already plug-and-play /ready-to-copy to save me typing? Many thanks in advance, W

Comment: Also check the code in [here](https://github.com/pkrumins/the-little-schemer)

Comment: Typing the code *yourself* is a very good way of improving learning. If you copy-and-paste it takes much longer to get a feel for what's correct.